# How to catch all types of sequelize Error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize@4.8.0 with expressJS.

I understand how to catch a specific type of sequelize Error and It works well.

```
return db.mySequel.transaction(t => {
    return db.users.findOrCreate({
        ...,
        transaction: t
    }).spread((rs, created) => {
        if (created == false) throw new Error("00001");
        return db.misc.bulkCreate([
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ], {
            transaction: t,
            raw: true
        });
    })
}).then(rs => {
    res.json(rs);
}).catch(db.mySequel.ForeignKeyConstraintError, err => {
   ... 
}).catch(err => {
   ...
});
```

But this query transaction process throw custom error instances too. So I want to catch all types of Sequelize Error separately from my errors.

Maybe I could make more catch chains, It seems verbose.
I tried `.catch(db.mySequel.BaseError` but not so helpful.

Comment: This is the error class in Sequelize implementation. You can view everything there: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/errors.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found inheritance relation among Error classes as document has mentioned.

and I could catch the relation with `Object.getInstanceOf()`method. `__proto__` property could make sense as well but I prefer more strict rule. (Though __proto__ is adopted most of javascript engine. It is just **De facto** standard.)

This is how I made:

```
var names = [];
(function p (inst) {
    if (inst != null) {
        var ofProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(inst);
        names.push(ofProto.constructor.name);
        p(ofProto);
    }
})(err);
console.log(names)
// ["ForeignKeyConstraintError", "DatabaseError", "BaseError", "Error", "Object"]
```

Now It is possible to find out where the error comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using multiple catch blocks use a single one and then test the `instanceof` of the object to determine how to handle the exception.

```
.catch(err => {
  if (err instanceof db.mySequel.ForeignKeyConstraintError) {
    // handle foreign key constraint
  } else {
    // handle other error
  }
});
```

Comment: I think an important point is to clarify that `instanceof` will check the object's whole prototype chain, so you can use the answer here in place of @BaroqueCode's more verbose answer below. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof